# WordPress - keeping admin privileges after switching users

Tags: wordpress, privileges

We have a client that is using Cart66 on their site. They want the option to accept checks and ship COD but only want admin users to have the ability to perform manual checkout, but in order to track a customers order history they want to place all orders through the site as the customer.

I guess my question boils down to this: is there a way to log in as an admin user then switch to a non-admin user yet keep admin privileges? They are wanting to switch to a regular user but keep the admin ability to manually check out.

They could switch the user to an admin, perform the transaction, then switch the user back to subscriber. Is there another way to keep admin privileges without these steps?

I hope that makes sense. If there is anyone out there that can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, no.  I've gotten around this by opening two different browsers.  I.e. I'll create two users: the admin account (my normal account), and then an alternate (test) account that's set as a subscriber.  I'll use my regular browser and log in as an administrator (my usual account), and then open an alternate browser, and log in as the test account.  So I'll have 2 windows open, but each window has a different account open in it.  Works just fine.  I get to see everything that happens as and admin *and* a subscriber at the same time.

It would be cool if you could do something like you're describing though - but I can see why you can't - you're getting into user roles and capabilities that would make no sense if you could do what you're describing.

I suppose *one* possibility would be to use the current logged-in-user's ID, and write  a function that would strip *front-end* capabilities (visually make them appear to be a logged-in subscriber), but it's a lot easier to just open two different browser windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shelly. My problem was basically that I wanted to temporally assign admin privileges to a non-admin user. I found a work around by customizing Cart66 and using a switch user plugin.